# What's the relationship between NetCDF dataset and ncdf4 class in R

Tags: r, netcdf

I want to process ERA reanalysis data in R so I install RNetCDF package and ncdf4 package.When I open my reanalysis file using open.nc() and nc_open() functions separately in two packages, I found my file class is ncdf4. But when I want to get my file's attribute,the dim.inq.nc() function reback error message :

```
setwd("D:/RTest/0601/")
d1 <- nc_open("T1.nc")
dimension <- dim.inq.nc(d1)
```

> Error: class(ncfile) == "NetCDF" is not TRUE

So I want to know the relationship between NetCDF and ncdf4 datasets.

Comment: Can you show us all the code you are doing to create that error, so that we can try and reproduce it. It sounds like only two or three lines but would be really helpful for us to help you. Also, if you can point us to one of the data files that would also help us help you.

Comment: Here's a walk-through for using NetCDF with R: https://scottishsnow.wordpress.com/2015/06/12/getting-started-with-netcdf-reading-ceh-gear/